# get web page and see if it is a login page

Tags: javascript, jquery

The user enters a URL into a text field and then I want to be able to get the webpage and see if it is a login page or not.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
$.get( 
        'http://somedomain.com/',
        { url: urlToScan }, in the url
        function(data) {

            //I want to check if the url given is a login page before the redirect.
            //I can do this before the get also

            if(urlIsLoginPage){
                //do not redirect
            }
            else{
                $.redirect('somedomain.com', {'local_test_results': JSON.stringify(data)});
            }
         }
         ).fail(function() {
             $("#scanInProgress").hide();
             $("#errorDuringScan").show();
          });
```

I was thinking about using `window.location` but I'm not sure if this will help because what if the url does not change for a login page?

Comment: You cannot access another domain with Ajax unless the domain is specifically setup to allow you to.

Comment: What would distinguish a login page?

Comment: I think I am going to have to parse the page a little and make that determination. What I have now works but it redirects when it is a login page. I mainly need to know how to get the content back.